# io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline expired before operation could complete

Tags: flink-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc, flink-cep, flink-batch, dataproc

In the dataproc cluster I am submitting the Flink job which reads the data from Pubsub.
When I am executing the flink job I am getting the below error.

We are using the flink version 1.12.5 and dataproc image version is
2.0.45-rocky8

The program finished with the following exception:

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: e3c28238136cce21ec060cb9962a121c)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:366)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:219)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: e3c28238136cce21ec060cb9962a121c)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.getJobExecutionResult(StreamContextEnvironment.java:123)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:80)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1782)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1765)
        at org.flink.ReadFromPubsub.main(ReadFromPubsub.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:349)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: e3c28238136cce21ec060cb9962a121c)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:125)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$24(RestClusterClient.java:670)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:575)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:943)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:123)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:118)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:80)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:233)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:215)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:666)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:89)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:446)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:305)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:212)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline expired before operation could complete.
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:271)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:252)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:165)
        at com.google.pubsub.v1.SubscriberGrpc$SubscriberBlockingStub.pull(SubscriberGrpc.java:1804)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:72)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:76)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:76)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:76)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.pull(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:66)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.PubSubSource.run(PubSubSource.java:113)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:66)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:267)
```

Also have a look at the pubsub configuration
ackDeadlineSeconds: 600
expirationPolicy:
ttl: 2678400s

Hod do I resolve this error.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this ?